# lodash convert object value(string) to number

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a very simple object like below. I am trying to use `lodash` as I am using it in other parts of my application. I am trying to find a way to convert the value of a specific key to a number.

In the example below, something like:

```
_.mapValues(obj.RuleDetailID, _.method('parseInt'))
```

---

**Object:**

```
var obj = [{
  "RuleDetailID": "11624",
  "AttributeValue": "172",
  "Value": "Account Manager",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}, {
  "RuleDetailID": "11626",
  "AttributeValue": "686",
  "Value": "Agent",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}, {
  "RuleDetailID": "11625",
  "AttributeValue": "180",
  "Value": "Analyst",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}, {
  "RuleDetailID": "11629",
  "AttributeValue": "807",
  "Value": "Individual Contributor",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}, {
  "RuleDetailID": "11627",
  "AttributeValue": "690",
  "Value": "Senior Agent",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}];
```

**Expected Output:**

```
var obj = [{
  "RuleDetailID": 11624,
  "AttributeValue": "172",
  "Value": "Account Manager",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}, {
  "RuleDetailID": 11626,
  "AttributeValue": "686",
  "Value": "Agent",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}, {
  "RuleDetailID": 11625,
  "AttributeValue": "180",
  "Value": "Analyst",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}, {
  "RuleDetailID": 11629,
  "AttributeValue": "807",
  "Value": "Individual Contributor",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}, {
  "RuleDetailID": 11627,
  "AttributeValue": "690",
  "Value": "Senior Agent",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}];
```

Is there a chain of methods I can whip together with `lodash` to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to use lodash to do this? This can be done with just JS

Comment: @VamshiGudipati - It doesn't "have" to be I guess, I just prefer the one-liners I can get out of using it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to *mutate* the original array, use `lodash#each`:

```
_.each(obj, item => item.RuleDetailID = parseInt(item.RuleDetailID, 10));
```

If you want to *create* a new array (don't mutate the original array), use `lodash#map` with `lodash#clone`:

```
let newArr = _.map(obj, item => {
  let newItem = _.clone(item);
  newItem.RuleDetailID = parseInt(newItem.RuleDetailID, 10);
  return newItem;
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean "If you want to mutate the array" for the each example, as each will mutate the array, whereas mutate will create a new array

Answer (score 1):

for mutating a single attribute of an object in an array i recommend the following:

- `each`: https://lodash.com/docs/#forEach

  - to loop through every object
- `update`: https://lodash.com/docs/#update

  - to update the value
- `parseInt`: https://lodash.com/docs/#parseInt

  - in your case to update the `RuleDetailID` attribute to a number instead of a string.

example on repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/AdvancedOilyParentheses#index.js

example:

```
_.each(arr, obj => _.update(obj, 'RuleDetailID', _.parseInt));
```

You used data: (FYI: I renamed `obj` to `arr` because is is not an object..)

```
var arr = [{
  "RuleDetailID": "11624",
  "AttributeValue": "172",
  "Value": "Account Manager",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}, {
  "RuleDetailID": "11626",
  "AttributeValue": "686",
  "Value": "Agent",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}, {
  "RuleDetailID": "11625",
  "AttributeValue": "180",
  "Value": "Analyst",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}, {
  "RuleDetailID": "11629",
  "AttributeValue": "807",
  "Value": "Individual Contributor",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}, {
  "RuleDetailID": "11627",
  "AttributeValue": "690",
  "Value": "Senior Agent",
  "IsValueRetired": "0"
}];
```